# Finding the slope of a line when the angle the line makes with the positive direction of the y-axis is given

Tags: angle, slope

[image: pic]

**Q:** What is the slope of the line that makes an angle $30^{\circ}$ with the positive direction of the y-axis?

**Answer 1:**

This is the answer given in my book. Line AB makes an angle $30^{\circ}$ with the positive direction of the y-axis. So, it makes an angle $120^{\circ}$ with the positive direction of the x-axis. So, the slope of AB, $m=\tan(120^{\circ})=-\sqrt{3}$.

**Answer 2:**

This is the answer given by me. I agree with the answer given in my book. However, I think that the line CD also makes an angle $30^{\circ}$ with the positive direction of the y-axis. So, it makes an angle $60^{\circ}$ with the positive direction of the x-axis. So, the slope of CD, $m=\tan(60^{\circ})=\sqrt{3}$.

Isn't the answer given by me aka answer 2 also correct?

Comment: Yes I think the question should have clarified that the angle with positive y-axis was being measured in counter-clockwise direction.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for your response! If you post this comment as an answer, I will accept it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's unspecified that the slope of the line is either positive or negative ,then both the answers are absolutely correct .
However , in your case , the question should have clarified the case , because it has taken the negative slope as the correct answer.